# Is there a bridge between Stanford's CoreNLP and OpenNLP parsers?

Tags: java, parsing, opennlp, stanford-nlp

I inherited a Java system that was written around CoreNLP, meaning that system classes use CoreNLP classes as fields in some places, in addition to using the CoreNLP parser.

I would like to test the system's accuracy with different parsers, and to that end I have refactored the code to use a generalized parser adapter, the subclasses of which should perform the necessary bridging between the CoreNLP API and the specific parser implementation.

Now, the subclass StanfordParserAdapter is trivial. My problem begins with the OpnNlpParserAdapter subclass. Is there an existing bridge between these parsers that I can use? If so, it will save me (and potentially others) a lot of work.

Example: Given a `List<HasWord>` to parse, CoreNLP produces a `Tree`. I would like the OpenNLP parser (through bridging code) to produce an equivalent Stanford `Tree` object when given the same input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that bridging is the optimal solution for this as it involves a lot of work and more time-taking than using Opennlp directly in your project.

On the other hand, configuring and using [Opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html) is quite easy. And there's a lot of support which you can use to parse your input.

comment if you need any help in configuring and using tools. A lot of examples are there to help.

Comment: I don't think bridging is the optimal solution either, but I'm not about to rewrite half the system just to use OpenNLP directly... :-/

I have no problem configuring or using OpenNLP (or other parsers for that matter), my question was specifically about the bridging code. It might be helpful to someone else, someday.

Comment: rewriting half the system? it's just adding the opennlp jars and creating a parser method, isn't it? :/

Comment: If you read the question's first sentence, you'll see that a lot of classes were written using Stanford classes. I wish I could just plug out the Stanford parser and plug in a new parser in its place...

Comment: I didn't get that. you have some data in hash table and you give it to the parser method written in opennlp, isn't that how it works?

Comment: I'll try to explain in more details. Parsing sentences is one of the preprocessing steps in the systems functionality. The input to the Stanford parser is a list of `HasWord` and the product is a `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree` object. The parse tree is kept as a field, and passed into methods of many classes, to read and manipulate. If I were to simply unplug the Stanford parser and plug the OpenNLP parser in its place, I'd have to correct all the code that leads up to the parse request and all the code that uses the output. I hope that makes more sense.